# Convert DAISY file to PDF Or PDF or Word document

Tags: file, pdf, converters, epub, file-conversion

I have a **DAISY zip** file downloaded from OpenLibrary.org. How can I convert it to pdf/epub/word document?

Comment: p.s.  I answered your question, but many would argue that it's not a programming question and so doesn't belong on SO.  You have been warned!  /cue scary music/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you are confused.  DAISY books are primarily audio books.
From http://www.daisy.org/about_us:

A DAISY book can be explained as a set of digital files that includes:

- One or more digital audio files containing a human narration of part or all of the source text;
- A marked-up file containing some or all of the text (strictly speaking, this marked-up text file is optional);
- A synchronization file to relate markings in the text file with time points in the audio file; and
- A navigation control file which enables the user to move smoothly between files while synchronization between text and audio is maintained.

The DAISY Standard allows the producing agency full flexibility regarding the mix of text and audio ranging from audio-only, to full text and audio, to text-only.

What this means to you is that the DAISY file you have from OpenLibrary.org might be only or primarily a digital audio file.  To convert that to pdf/epub/word, you would need a speech-to-text convertor.  If the marked-up text file does contain all of the text, it shouldn't be hard to convert.  DAISY readers are available for free on the web.  To get one from DAISY, go here: http://www.daisy.org/tobi/upgrading-daisy-books-epub, which should definitely do the job.